# Monotouch - How do I style the Header at the beginning of a grouped section?

Tags: header, xamarin.ios

I am a total Monotouch n00bie and i'm really struggling to find out how to change the font and rowsize of a grouped section header.

I am creating my IUTableViewSource and attaching it to my UITableView but where is the syntax to change all the section headers? (the ones above each grouped section).

I've looked through the XCode IB and guessed tableView.Header/Section/HeaderFont/Style etc

Coming from ASP.NET c# this is hard work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with MonoTouch.Dialog easily.

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

It also comes with MonoTouch, just add the reference to it and add the using statement and you are good to go!

```
RootElement root = new RootElement("MyRootName");
Section mySection = new Section();
UIView mySectionHeaderView = // Do stuff here to make your custom header. Add UILabels, etc etc.
mySection.HeaderView = mySectionHeaderView;

StringElement strElement = new StringElement("This is a table cell"); // just to get you started
mySection.Add(strElement); // Add element to the section.
root.Add(mySection); // Add my section to the root element.
Root = root; // Sets my temp root, to the DialogViewControllers actual Root. You do this rather than working directly on Root to stop some display issues.
```

This assumes that you get MonoTouch.Dialog and your class is subclassed of a DialogViewController. Once I found out about this MT.D I rarely go and use regular UITableViews anymore!